# Javascript if form.pass location= open a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script that opens up another file but I want it to open a webpage like www.google.com or www.yahoo.com

```
function pasuser(form) {
    if (form.id.value=="user") { 
        if (form.pass.value=="password") {              
            location = "file:///C:/Users/......Music.html" 
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Password")
        }
    } else {  
        alert("Invalid UserID")
    }
}
```

Comment: So what about it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `location.href`

```
location.href = "www.google.com";
```

Comment: Assigning directly to `location` works too. The main issue is... just put a URL! `location = http://google.com/` - note, scheme is required!